# dhclient appears to give address but interface does not get assigned it

Tags: wifi, dhcp, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I am trying to connect to wifi using wpa_supplicant. I use this config:

```
network={
ssid="guest"
#psk="guest"
psk=<numbers>
}
```

I also tried this config:

```
update_config=1
network={
        ssid="Guest"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        group=CCMP TKIP
        psk=<numbers>
        }
```

I run this command:

```
wpa_supplicant  -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And it appears to connect and auth:

```
rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
wlan0: Trying to associate with e8:04:62:23:57:d0 (SSID='Guest' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with e8:04:62:23:57:d0
wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with e8:04:62:23:57:d0 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to e8:04:62:23:57:d0 completed (auth) [id=0 id_str=]
```

I try to get an address via dhcp and it appears to work from the messages, however there is no IP address assigned to wlan0 and I have no internet access as a result.

```
[root@switch /]# dhclient -v wlan0                                              
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1.1-P1                                
Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.                                
All rights reserved.                                                            
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/                       

Listening on LPF/wlan0/74:da:38:0a:38:3d                                        
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/74:da:38:0a:38:3d                                        
Sending on   Socket/fallback                                                    
DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67                                 
DHCPACK from 10.10.100.1                                                        
bound to 10.10.100.180 -- renewal in 2912 seconds.
```

Any ideas why the wlan0 does not get an address?

EDIT: I see syslog has this message but not sure what it means

```
rtw_wx_set_mlme, cmd=0, reason=3
```

EDIT:

If I statically assign the leased address and add a default gateway manually it works. But only if I add the leased address.